# Remote access to server

Tags: ssh, unix

I am new to the networking environment and I am trying to log into a Linux system with a SSH client on a Mac but I an having trouble.

I found the terminal and clicked on it and a bash 80 times 24 window comes in with the following:

```
Last login: Sat Sep 21 15:33:10 on xxxx
Aarons-MacBook-Air:~ aaronxxxxx$
```

I put x to hide any personal information. After playing around I found the new remote connection but after this step I am super lost and would like some guidance.

I have the server name, and my login and password but I have typed that all in and am having no success any help will be super awesome.

Comment: I have no idea what you are talking about. What is your question?

Comment: What are you trying to do? You opened up a macOS terminal window and now you need to login to a remote server, correct? Then you need to enter `ssh [username]@[hostname]` and then enter your password. Of course `[username]` should be your username and `[hostname]` should be the name of the host you are trying to login to. If the solution I describe is not the solution, then you need to very clearly state your problem and issue.

Answer (score 0):

When you launch Terminal, it starts up `bash` on your local machine. That's what you're interacting with in your example.

To ssh to another host, use the `ssh` command, by typing something like:

```
ssh user-id@remote-host
```

where *user-id* is the account you have on the remote machine, and *remote-host* is either the hostname or IP address of your remote host.

If the connection is successful, you'll be prompted for a password.

At this point, you'll have a shell session on your remote host. But based on your questions here, you'll want to learn more about using bash in general, otherwise this bash session won't be that useful. Here is a [bash tutorial](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/Bash-Beginners-Guide.html), but there are tons of them on the Internet.